# Failed Database Connection between OpenShift Server and Mlab.com?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, mlab

I'm hoping to host a node.js server at OpenShift, utilizing a MongoDB database hosted at mlab.com (the new version of mongolab.com)  Here's a [pretty straight forward tutorial.](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/11-mongolab)  According to that tutorial, things seem pretty straight forward. That tutorial may be a bit dated, but seems to have been targeted directly for my application (less the update from Mongolab --> mlab) I've used Mongolab in the past and they provide a great service.

So I've built my database.  I've written my node code and tested it from local host, where it works great.  Yes there are a few lines of difference, but not much.  I'm using the same git directory as I'm pushing to OpenShift.  The code is pretty straight forward.

```
databaseUrl = 'mongodb://UserNameHere:PasswordHere@ds012345.mlab.com:12345/DataBaseName';
if (process.env.MLAB_URI) {
    databaseUrl = process.env.MLAB_URI;
}

MongoClient.connect(databaseUrl, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err, "Database Connection Troubles: " + err);
```

test process.env.MLAB_URI from my terminal after a RHC login.

```
[ABC-XYZ.rhcloud.com xxxxxxxxxxx]\> echo $MLAB_URI
mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds012345.mlab.com:12345/DataBaseName
[ABC-XYZ.rhcloud.com xxxxxxxxxxx]\> echo $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo/
```

Test with `$`, use in code with `process.env.` call.  Obviously I've changed my username, password and Openshift server identification, but I've checked and there appear to be no spelling errors.  I get the same fail on openshift if I don't use the MLAB_URI environment variable.  It's like the connection from the OpenShift server is shut off.

Mlab does provide some tools to verify the connection to a MongoDB there. [Here's  link to the Mlab assist stuff.](http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help)   I can ping the mlab location from a RHC login and it works just fine.  Unfortunately I'm unable to do the `% netcat -w 3 -v ds012345.mlab.com 12345` test.  That tool (netcat / nc) isn't available at OpenShift.

Again, this thing works fine when I run my node file.js from my local host.  I can see data being deposited at the mlab server.  It fails if I run from Openshift, with a

```
throw err ^
AssertionError: Database Connection Troubles: MongoError: auth failed
```

The code works fine if I use a MongoDB cartridge in the same gear at OpenShift.  Unfortunately I've got a few different servers at different locations that are all sharing information.  Anybody know what's going on here?

Update: I've done some additional testing from a terminal with RHC login to OpenShift.

```
[ABC-XYZ.rhcloud.com xxxxxxxxxxx]\> mongo ds012345.mlab.com:12345/dbName -u <dbuser> -p <password>;
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.6.xyz.xyz:27017/admin
Fri Mar 11 04:14:52.770 Error: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
exception: login failed
```

The one surprise is that connecting to: url:27017/admin line... I'd like to understand that better.  Stay tuned.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a networking issue, but exactly as the error says it's and "auth failed" issue. So the credentials you are using don't match the connection. I note you use the term `"collectionName"` in the question, where in fact it's `"databaseName"`. Could it be that you have this confused and are trying to connect to a database that does not exist? With a user account that does not have permission to create a database? ( which BTW, I hope the account does not have that permission ).

Comment: @BlakesSeven  CollectionName... ooops. Brain fart.  I will update my original.  No, its the database name. You are exactly correct.  Thx.   And the actual code does indicate the correct DB name.  Remember I'm using EXACTLY the same code in the same directory when I test via LocalHost.  I got totally different results.  Data gets added to the DB when I run localhost, but auth fails when I try the same trick via OpenShift.  Its got to be some sort of permission issue.  I'm wondering if this couldn't be a port issue at OpenShift.  If I remember correctly they have some odd requirements..

Comment: I don't suppose you have anything else to connect to the instance from your openshift VM? Do you have permissions to install the `mongotools` package? Have you tried even connecting from your own machine using the same URI? Like I said, an "auth error" means that the user/password is not recognized or does not have permission to connect to the database namespace you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first comment.  I'm able to get my OpenShift code to obtain data from other sources (via node package X-ray).  I'm able to ping mlab.com from RHC.    I've never touched mongotools.  I thought that was to manage a MongoDB if stored @ OpenShift.  I did build a mongodb at this gear in OpenShift, and I've been using it, but I now realize I need to have different servers utilize the same data.  The auth login/password code is built into the `mongodb://` line, and that works fine from localhost. I understand how inconsistent this all sounds, that's what I see.

Comment: I can try some mongo command line tools to attempt to link from OpenShift over to mlab and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for anybody else who may get here.  I submitted a support request to mlab.  I received an immediate response (Awesome support!)

> You'll need to upgrade your mongo shell version to 3.0+ in order to
>   connect and authenticate to an mLab Sandbox database server. It looks
>   like version 2.4.9 is being used.

So I was definitely using mongo shell version 3.0 from my localhost.  I have little control @ OpenShift for that command line feature.. But whoa... Let's not forget the big picture here.  I'm really trying to use my node server to contact mlab via a `var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;` connect call.  Let's make the same check.  Do I have the latest version of mongodb listed in my package.json file?  Oops..

Easy fix.  Update package.json to require a newer version of mongodb.   Success at OpenShift.  Yipee!